# Copying Multiple Data Types to Clipboard in React JS

Tags: reactjs, clipboard, mime

I am trying to copy an image and text to the clipboard. Works fine on safari but not on chrome.

```
handleCopy = () => {
        const { imgSrc } = this.props;
      
        try {
          // Convert Base64 string to Blob
          const byteCharacters = atob(imgSrc);
          const byteArrays = [];
      
          for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteArrays.push(byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i));
          }
      
          const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(byteArrays)], { type: 'image/png' });
          const text = "Text";

          const clipboardData = new ClipboardItem([
            new ClipboardItem({ 'text/plain': text }),
            new ClipboardItem({ 'image/png': blob })
          ]);
      
          navigator.clipboard.write([clipboardData])
            .then(() => {
              console.log('Items copied to clipboard!');
              this.setState({ copied: true });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error('Error copying items to clipboard:', error);
            });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error copying items to clipboard:', error);
        }
      };
```

Throwing error:
`Error copying image: DOMException: Support for multiple ClipboardItems is not implemented.`

Is there a way, supported on all browsers to copy an image and text to clipboard? I would not like to use a URL to save the image, but keep it as a PNG. This is meant to be shared via text message.